# What's the difference between proxy and redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I want to *serve* all requests coming to `/` as if they were coming to `/api/`. For example,

`/posts/` should be treated as `/api/posts/`

As far as I know this is proxying but I am uncertain about the difference between proxying and redirecting. The main confusion comes from the fact that while `redirect` sets the response header's status code to `302` while proxy sets it to `200`.

What's the difference between proxying, and what's the best way for me to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you may want is called [rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine): when a request comes in for a particular endpoint, it gets rewritten to something that the HTTP server can handle.

With Express, you can do that using a custom middleware function:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // If the current request doesn't start with `/api`...
  if (req.url.indexOf('/api') !== 0) {
    // ...rewrite it by prefixing it with `/api`.
    req.url = '/api' + req.url;
  }
  next();
});
```

You'll have to include that before your routes, so it gets called before them.

This will be completely transparent to the client: they think that they are getting back the response for `/posts` even though internally, it's handled by the `/api/posts` handler.

If you want it to be explicit, through redirects, you can use the following:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.indexOf('/api') !== 0) {
    return res.redirect('/api' + req.url);
  }
  next();
});
```

This isn't transparent at all. It tells the client: *"Hey, you tried to request `/posts`, but instead you need to direct your request to `/api/posts`"*. This means an extra request has to be made by the client.

Proxying is basically an elaborate way of doing the rewriting, but instead of just modifying the request so it ends up at the right handler, an actual internal HTTP request is made to `/api/posts`, the result of which is sent back to the client. In your situation it's overkill (proxying is generally used to pass requests to *other* HTTP servers).